# AAPT err(Facade for 14859372): /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2

Tags: react-native

```
    suresh@suresh-Lenovo-G560:~/Desktop/native/fucking$ react- 
    native run-android


    Starting JS server...
    Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew 
    installDebug)...

    > Configure project :app
    WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.3) is 
    ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3)for 
    Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
    Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
    To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'" from 
    your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin 
    now has a default version of the build tools.

    AAPT err(Facade for 29760477): /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build- 
    tools/27.0.3/aapt2: 1: /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build- 
    tools/27.0.3/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
    Slave 29760477 failed to start
    java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make  
    sure the current build tools (located at 
    /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2) are not corrupted.
      atcom.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail
    (AaptProcess.java:193) at com.android.builder.
    internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation
    (AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:250)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
     Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_2" 
     java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%1$s'
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2525)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.
    AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.shouldDowngrade
    (AaptGradleFactory.java:156)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.
    AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.error
    (AaptGradleFactory.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:253)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
      AAPT err(Facade for 7895191): /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build- 
     tools/27.0.3/aapt2: 1: /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build- 
     tools/27.0.3/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
     Slave 7895191 failed to start
     java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make 
     sure the current build tools (located at 
     /home/suresh/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2) are not corrupted.
        at   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail
    (AaptProcess.java:193)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.
      creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:250)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Exception in thread 
     "queued-resource-processor_1" java.util.
     MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%1$s'
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2525)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.
    AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.shouldDowngrade
    (AaptGradleFactory.java:156)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.
    AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.error 
    (AaptGradleFactory.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:253)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

     > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
      Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
     java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs 
     for details.


     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

     * What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
     > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
     java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs 
     for details.

    * Try:
      Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
      or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan toget full   
      insights.

     * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 10s
     9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
     Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for 
    details.
    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected 
    and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: What is your operating system? AAPT2 only works on 32 bit Windows, and 64 bit Windows, Linux and MacOS.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio and all the build tools (including AAPT2) does not support Linux 32 bit. The only supported systems are:

- Windows 32 bit
- Windows 64 bit
- Mac OS 64 bit
- Linux 64 bit

Try a different machine/OS/VM that matches one of these systems/architectures.